# How to add margin to aligned component in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, margin

I use a RelativeLayout with some widgets on it. I have a RadioGroup and a TextView and I'd like the textview to be aligned to the radiogroup AND add a margin to it to make it slightly inner than the radiogroup.

Here is my code:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroupSync"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/labelTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radioFull"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/lblFull"
          />

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radioPart"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/lblPart" />
    </RadioGroup>
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/radiogroupSync"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radiogroupSync"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="2010.01.01."
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    />
```

Obviously the TextView isn't margined by 100dp, even if I remove the alignLeft. How can I set margin for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margin doesn't work with Align. You can use left padding instead.

A bit offtopic, but I wouldn't recommend using odd numbers for margins/paddings in dp - the reason is that, for example, 3dp scaled for hdpi would be 4.5 pixels and that would be a problem in some cases.

Comment: Is it intentional to ignore margins? I don't use odd numbers, I always use even (see 100dp or 16 sp)Request clarification or suggest improvements.

Comment: I was referring to this line in your <TextView/>:
android:layout_margin="3dp"

I'm not sure if it's intentional, but I guess the implementation of align sets the same values that the margins set, only with a higher precedence.